# Payment Gateway in UK that can hold funds like escrow?

Tags: stripe-payments, opayo, worldpay, realex-payments-api

I want payment gateway that can hold my funds like escrow and release them to seller account after confirmation.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic here. However, you may find better luck [SoftwareRecs.SE](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Answer (score 0):

the gateway you need is Nochex. I'm guessing you want to offer sub-accounts to other sellers and release funds to the account holders according to your timeline?